# Simple coordinate transformation using gdal library C++

Tags: gdal, utm

I'd like to convert a coordinate from EPSG:5179 to EPSG:32652 and vice versa.

I've built gdal library and linked to my VS project, but I have no clue how to do it.
I've looked through the website but couldn't find the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the gdaltransform program to convert a geographic coordinate from one projection to another.

For example;

```
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:28992 -t_srs EPSG:31370
177502 311865
```

And the output will be in EPSG:31370 projection as defined in the -t_srs flag

If you want you can also develop this for multiple coordinates with a bash scripting language. If your problem is more specific can you please share an example to help us in order to answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did it with PROJ library cause I couldn't find a good C++ example of it.

Answer (score 0):

GDAL uses PROJ to perform [coordinate transformations](https://proj.org/operations/transformations/), so I'm guessing you have that too.

Take a look at the [Quick start for C++ API usage](https://proj.org/development/quickstart_cpp.html) to get started.